# javascript change iframe location when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a lot of links on the same page. The links will start different downloads.
What i want to do is that when a link is clicked to start a download, i also want to change the iframe location to a php page to increment a download hits counter.

The code needs to be in an `onClick` event on each links since i have so many on the same page.

I want something like this:

```
<a href="download001.zip" onClick="iframe.location.href='hits_counter.php?file=download001>Start download 001</a><br>
<a href="download002.zip" onClick="iframe.location.href='hits_counter.php?file=download002>Start download 003</a><br>
<a href="download003.zip" onClick="iframe.location.href='hits_counter.php?file=download003>Start download 003</a><br>
...
```

Both events must be activated : download the file AND change the iframe href

Comment: Why don't you just make the PHP script both count *and* serve the content?

Answer (score 0):

if you have many, onClick is not the solution

using jquery you can handle all of them with a thing like that :

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $.get("hits_counter.php",{ file:$(this).attr("href") });
});
```

and no need for the iframe anymore

Comment: i really need to use the iframe because the hits counter is on a different server and i cant get cross-domain submit to work.... also the value of "file=" (get) is different than the href.... i was just using it to simplify my examples

Answer (score 0):

You can serve the file and increment the counter from the server side. The code for sending a file for download is as follows. So your hits_counter.php can be something like this

```
$file = $_GET['filename'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);

  //increment counter based on file name
  exit;
}
```

Source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: problem is that i don't have mysql on the server hosting the files. The hit counter needs to be on another server, thats why i thought about sending the query to an iframe